# Unconditional Love: A Journey of Two Souls

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

And now, a 500 word excerpt from ChatGPT's new book, "Unconditional Love: A Journey of Two Souls," available now on Amazon First Reads - free with Prime.

> With laughter, Oscar and Vivian were explaining to their friends Ivan and Samantha how they each thought they had exceeded the other's expectations for a lover and romantic partner, but reality quickly mocked them for their ignorance.
> They soon found marriage reveals everyone's little (or big) flaws and idiosyncracies, those crazy habits and inexplicable reactions that make one cheerful or tearful; things to commend or which offend, to respect or reject, to idolize or criticize about the other. Nobody is perfect; being together, every day, in the same house, made Oscar and Vivian realize they loved each other, but hadn't expected those quirks each had kept unrevealed.
>
> Mutual affection and adoration let them grin and bear it. Oscar loved everything about Vivian, every bit of crazy included. She was The One. Why she loved *him* he'd never know; one thing he *did* know, though, was that he had finally found love and friendship, joy and laughter, in a partner who made him feel loved and cherished equally in return. As for Vivian, she too was crazy about her Oscar; she loved him completely, warts and all, and he made her very happy. Indeed, it really was no hardship getting to know each other better. Their days were filled with laughter, their nights with passion, and their hearts with love.
>
> Now they were happily sharing their first experiences of married life with their younger friends. They knew Ivan and Samantha anticipated their own nuptials in a few months, and wanted to escape some of the traps that ruin the happy harmony for many young couples. Ivan had sought out Oscar, his friend since childhood, knowing he'd do everything short of prescribing Xanax to impart some words of wisdom to ease Ivan's understandable anxiety. Samantha, likewise, turned to Vivian for practical tips to avoid some of the pitfalls that she worried about. Eventually, this night out for both couples had been arranged, bringing the four friends together for dinner, decadent dessert, and enjoyable conversation and camaraderie. Sharing many anecdotes from their own trials and triumphs, Oscar and Vivian now seemed determined to have fun giving each other a hard time, indulging their playful sides.
>
> Oscar told them how Vivian once biked to the store, intending to get a jar of Nutella, but instead had gotten sprayed by a skunk! This meant she'd had to go into the store, embarrassed by her own awful reek, to get tomato juice instead. Like, nine cans of the stuff. ("That was all they had in stock!", nodded Vivian ruefully.) She couldn't put the bike in the garage for three weeks; stink inundated the house otherwise. And her clothes ended in the garbage. Triple bagged.
>
> Vivian gave as good as she got, telling everyone how Oscar once ran a young man out of the pharmacy for "messing up all the shelves," not realizing the owner had hired his teenaged son to audit the inventory!
>
> Love sometimes does NOT make sense.
> But enjoy it if you've got it.

**What message does ChatGPT have for you?**

Comment: I'll just leave [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db8ns.png) here. :)

Comment: In case you're curious: (1) ChatGPT did in fact write "the message" and, as noted in an earlier comment, also supplied the name of the "book". (2) Amazon First Reads is a real thing, described on the page seen by Prime members as "Early access to an editors' pick, free with Prime". (3) I wrote the "book excerpt" - the people and most of the events described are fictitious. (4) Having said that, the bike/skunk/store thing really did happen to someone I know. (5) ChatGPT may have written the exact message, but it doesn't take an AI to know it's on point. Today, and every day, celebrate Love.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As hinted by the introductory text, ...

> *[...] available now on Amazon **First Reads** - free with **Prime**.*
>
>  ... we take all the prime-positioned words in the excerpt - the 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 7th, and so on - and read their first letters. This spells out a message:
>
>  **Love is the prime factor in the equation of life, solving the mystery of existence and giving meaning to everything.**